# C. D. Broad’s taxonomy of philosophical styles and theories?

Tags: reference-request, wittgenstein

I came across a reference to,

> [C. D. Broad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._D._Broad)’s taxonomy of philosophical styles and theories, given in
>   Broad’s series of undergraduate lectures, "Elements of Philosophy"

in Ray Monk's biography, *Ludwig Wittgenstein: The Duty of Genius*.

What is the basic structure of this taxonomy (and can it be viewed online -- I don't see "Elements of Philosophy" listed among Broad's [works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._D._Broad#Works))?

Comment: Hello. Something that _is_ listed there is Broad's [_Five Types of Ethical Theory_](http://www.ditext.com/broad/ftet/ftet.html)

Comment: Can't find that series of lectures printed up anywhere. It appears that the original reference is in [Wittgenstein's Lectures 1930-1932](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/kw/wittgenstein's-lectures-cambridge-1930-1932-from-the-notes-of-john-king-and-desmond-lee-wittgenstein-ludwig/) if that's any help. I spent an hour digging, I fear they may be lost to time. An amusing note about Broad from *Wittgenstein's Poker* follows …

Comment: “'Reliable rather than brilliant' had been Russell's early and perceptive assessment of Broad when, in Wittgenstein's shadow, he had been Russell's pupil. As a teacher, he had donnish foibles that are the stuff of reminiscence at reunion dinners. He used to script his lectures fully in advance, and then read each sentence aloud, twice. The jokes he read out three times. That, says Maurice Wiles, who attended Broad's lectures, was the only way one could tell what was a joke. When his course was interrupted by a term sabbatical, Broad began the first lecture after his absence with 'Point D ...”

Comment: Priceless. You could not make this stuff up.

Comment: David Chalmers in* Blackwell Guide to phphy of mind* (p102) mentions Broad's taxonomy and refers to his *The Mind and its Place in Nature (1925)*, giving also this link http://www.ditext.com/broad/mpn14.html#t.

Answer (score 1):

You find Broads Lectures "Elements of Philosophy" as unpublished typescript in

Broad, Charlie Dunbar, Elements of Philosophy, unveröffentlichtes Vorlesungstyposkript, Broad C2/5, im Archiv der Wren Library des Trinity College, Cambridge.